# What's a more professional or formal way to say that someone is "cowering/hiding behind their keyboard"?

Tags: grammar, sentence, formality

I am trying to explain how a lot of people online have a lack of accountability on the internet by hiding behind their keyboards.

Comment: Unclear what you mean.  "Evading responsibility", perhaps?

Comment: One of my favourite terms, though not at all professional or formal, is ***keyboard warrior***. On-topic, ***hiding behind anonymity*** is probably one I'd consider using. Or Hot Licks' suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, hiding behind anonymity is good enough for me thanks!

Comment: Shall I post it as an answer, then? Usually I wouldn't because the question didn't cite prior research to find a term, and it may be closevoted because of that. If you can, I would consider editing it to include anything you did to find a term before you asked us.

Comment: Another variant on @john-clifford's suggestion is that trolls & cyber-stalkers **hide behind a cloak of anonymity**.